# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://...' from origin 'http://...' has been blocked by CORS policy(Spring Boot & Angular 7)

Tags: spring-boot, http-post, angular7, same-origin-policy

I am creating a sample application using Spring Boot and Angular 7. In spring boot I am converting http to https. In angular application the client side post functionality cannot call the server Api post method.

It throws the below error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:8082/Demo/list' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**Client Side** Angular 7

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  firstClick() {
    return console.log('clicked');
  }
  getList() {
    return this.http.get('https://localhost:8082/Demo/list');
  }
}
```

**Client Side**

```
  constructor(private data: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.data.getList().subscribe(data => {
       this.tempList = data
       console.log(this.tempList);
     });
  }
```

**Server**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@Controller
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Spring Security you should enable localhost domain to allow access, or allow all domain to access(not secure)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/cors.html

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource
            .cors().and()
            ...
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Updated:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#cors

Comment: Updated link to CORS doc on Spring website is [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#cors)

Comment: what's should I replace with the "..."? It's a syntax error for me!

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable localhost domain to allow access. And then create a bean of it.

```
public class CORSFilter extends GenericFilterBean implements Filter {
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "*");
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);

}
```

}

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean(){
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CORSFilter());
    registrationBean.setName("CORS FIlter");
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    registrationBean.setOrder(1);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

This works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty simple and elegant solution has been `Spring 4.2.x` `CORS` documentation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

Here is the link,
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html#_global_cors_configuration

Although from `Spring 5.1.x` `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated, so instead `WebMvcConfigurer` should be used.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if u are using JWT filter chain or any other OncePerRequestFilter then you have to configured properly to handle preflight (OPTIONS) requests.
You don't have to worry it will not affect your actual authentication logic. If you pass authorization header if needed ,it will work fine with your logic

```
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    // Your JWT filter implementation...

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // ... Your existing filter logic

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            // For preflight requests, set the CORS headers and allow the request to continue without authentication.
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200"); // Replace with your Angular frontend URL
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            return;
        }

        // ... Your existing filter logic for authenticated requests
    }
}
```

Also need to create bean of webMvcConfigration for globally allowing CORS for all of your controller

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ABCApplication {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper  modelMapper(){
        return new ModelMapper();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ABCApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200") // Replace with your Angular app URL
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS") // Allowed HTTP methods
                        .allowedHeaders("*") // Allowed request headers (you can customize this based on your requirements)
                        .allowCredentials(true);
            }
        };
    }

}
```