# SOLVED - Write to Angular 9 Socket from Java Spring - Blocked by CORS Policy

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, sockjs

I am running into an issue attempting to open a SockJS socket in an Angular 9 application and write to this socket from a Spring backend using the SimpMessageTemplate. The main goal of this task is to receive and display incoming data in realtime with out polling.

I based my original implementation off of an existing [repository](https://github.com/mouadelfakir/websocket-angular-spring-boot-example) done by [mouadelfakir](https://github.com/mouadelfakir) but the implementation used older versions of the software (Angular ~1 and Spring Boot ~1.5). When updating to newer versions, the Angular 9 update provided no change in how the application worked but upgrading to Spring Boot 2.2.6 breaks the implementation.

Upon the Angular application trying to connect to the back end Spring application, the console outputs the following two errors:

```
- Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/websocket-backend/socket/info?t=1589733936852' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
- GET http://localhost:8080/websocket-backend/socket/info?t=1589733936852 net::ERR_FAILED
```

At the time of writing this post, I have tried a lot of the other remedies that I have seen recommended online, such as creating a proxy that the Angular application run ons or implementing a filter to add the Cross-Origin-Request-Policy in Spring but nothing has worked. A majority of these posts were older and I feel that they may no longer be valid due to the updated software.

Here is my [current fork](https://github.com/jakeocinco/websocket-angular-spring-boot-example) of the example repository that I used which features the software upgrades that I am trying to use.

Edit: Thanks for the feedback on this I was able to resolve the issue. It was caused by the upgrade to the newer version of Spring but was actually due to the deprecation of a key the original develop used in application.properties that kept slipping by me. Updated code exists on my [current fork](https://github.com/jakeocinco/websocket-angular-spring-boot-example) should anyone need it.

Comment: Try enabling access to localhost domain. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54327963/access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-https-from-origin-http-has-been-bloc

Answer (score 0):

The example you're using is 2 years old. Even nowadays not all browsers have a built-in CORS support, hence the issue.

so your application never actually connects to the socket. Your browser first sends a request to the backend asking for the socket info and that request fails, because your backend doesn't specify the CORS headers. Or more specifically, the request succeeds, but the browser refuses to process the response (even if have some legitimate JS code to process the response) because the CORS headers don't match the data that your application represents.

On the high level, you probably want your backend to return the following headers

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin - either your DNS where the UI is hoster (like `http://localhost:8080`) or `*`. This header can have only 1 value. It's not a list.
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods - comma-separated list of HTTP methods that the browser is allowed to make, so either `GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS` or again just `*`
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers - a comma-separated list of all headers that the browser is allowed to send to the backend, so `authorization, user-agent, host, accept, content-type...` or `*`.

Here's a good example of how to set this up: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server-allowed-origins

```java
@Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(myHandler(), "/myHandler").setAllowedOrigins("http://test.com");
    }
```

basically you need to call the `setAlowedOrigins` with your domain (aka. http://localhost:*your port if any*) or `*`. I suppose setting the other CORS headers would also be beneficial for the full browser support